# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Photo'

Tags: ios, swift, api, pagination, alamofire

Currently practicing pagination with API and getting error message *Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Photo'* . Im using the Alamofire library for the get response.

Here's my struct:

```
struct Photo: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let url: String
}
```

and the method for implementing pagination:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var limit = 20
    let totalEntries = 100
    
    private var photos: [Photo] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupTableView()
        self.fetchData()
        
        var index = 0
        while index < limit {
            photos.append(index) // ERROR here
            index = index + 1
        }
    }
```

The API call:

```
private func fetchData() {
        AF.request(self.url + "/photos", method: .get).responseDecodable(of: [Photo].self) { [weak self] response in
            self?.photos = response.value ?? []
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

and the willDisplay method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == photos.count - 1 {
            if photos.count < totalEntries {
                var index = photos.count
                limit = index + 20
                while index < limit {
                    photos.append(index) // ERROR here
                    index = index + 1
                }
                self.perform(#selector(loadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @objc func loadTable() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Please help me out

Comment: You can’t append an index (Int) to the  array, you need to append a Photo object. Do you know how to work with a table view without pagination? If not then I suggest you start there so you first get that working before having a go at pagination

Comment: You need to append only Photo type object to Photo like:  photos.append(Type<Photo>)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah guess I should study tableview more

Comment: as it mentioned above photos contain object type photos not int. so use this photos.append(photo[index])